# How to Convert userip to integer in AMAZON REDSHIFT

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

just starting to play around and test amazon's redshift. One thing I need to do that i can easily do in sql is change userip to integer. This is done in mssql with a scalar function that uses parsename to break up the ip numbres and multiple by them by constants.

```
 CAST(

       (CAST(PARSENAME(@IP,4) AS BIGINT) * 16777216) +
       (CAST(PARSENAME(@IP,3) AS BIGINT) * 65536) +
       (CAST(PARSENAME(@IP,2) AS BIGINT) * 256) +
        CAST(PARSENAME(@IP,1) AS BIGINT) 
  AS BIGINT)
```

That is what it looks likes for reference.

As i expected parsename is not a function in redshift and thus my question arises. Do you guys know of a way i can achieve the same resuslt?

Figured it out:

( LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1) * 16777216) + (LEFT(SUBSTRING(ip_address, LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')+1)), LEN(ip_address) - LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1)) - LEN(LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1)) - 2), STRPOS( SUBSTRING(ip_address, LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')+1)), LEN(ip_address) - LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1)) - LEN(LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1)) - 2), '.')-1) * 65536) + (RIGHT( SUBSTRING(ip_address, LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')+1)), LEN(ip_address) - LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1)) - LEN(LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1)) - 2), LEN(SUBSTRING(ip_address, LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')+1)), LEN(ip_address) - LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1)) - LEN(LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1)) - 2)) - STRPOS(SUBSTRING(ip_address, LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')+1)), LEN(ip_address) - LEN(LEFT(ip_address, STRPOS(ip_address, '.')-1)) - LEN(LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1)) - 2), '.') ) * 256) + (REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(ip_address), STRPOS(REVERSE(ip_address), '.')-1) ) * 1 )

Comment: "in sql" -> "In Microsoft SQL Server"? "SQL" is the query language, it's not a product. Thanks for mentioning that you're using Redshift (a proprietary fork by ParAccel of an extremely old PostgreSQL version) not just saying "PostgreSQL" though. Also, better to post an answer to your own question rather than editing your answer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, my eyes are watering at the sight of that query, though I'm sure you don't have tons of choice given the restrictions imposed by Redshift.

I'm still amazed you have to do something quite that cumbersome. Can't you at least create an `SQL` function or two to tidy it up? Or does Redshift not even support `CREATE FUNCTION ... LANGUAGE sql`?

For reference, in proper PostgreSQL you'd do:

```
select (split_part(ip, '.', 1)::bigint << 24) +
       (split_part(ip, '.', 2)::bigint << 16) +
       (split_part(ip, '.', 3)::bigint << 8) +
       (split_part(ip, '.', 4)::bigint);
```

or using a simple-ish SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inet_to_bigint(inet) AS $$
SELECT sum(split_part($1::text,'.',octetnum)::bigint << (32 - octetnum*8))
FROM generate_series(1,4) octetnum;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

or, almost certainly most efficiently, by abusing the `inet` data type's subtraction operator:

```
SELECT (ip - '0.0.0.0')
```

(This one might even work in Redshift if they've retained the `inet` data type and if this feature existed back in PostgreSQL 8.1, when ParAccel forked from PostgreSQL).

On a side note, I was quite astonished to see that there's no cast defined from `inet` to bigint, in PostgreSQL, as I expected to just be able to write `'127.0.0.1'::inet::bigint`, which would be shorthand for `CAST(CAST('127.0.0.1' AS inet) AS bigint)`.

Comment: Redshift does not support functions, or IP types

Comment: +1 . . . The first solution appears to work in RedShift.

Answer (score 1):

`split_part(ip, '.', n)` should do it.

Comment: I tried useing that already @jakub but when using amazon redshift, split_part will not work outside of the master node.

Comment: @PatRickAllen These things are worth mentioning in the original question. "I already tried ..." . Amazon don't offer a convenient way to test stuff on Redshift (no SQLFiddle equivalent, no free test servers, etc) so if you tag a question [tag:postgresql] people are going to reply with answers that work for PostgreSQL.